# Is this sprintf call broken in 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby

At the bottom of [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962)'s documentation it has this example:

```
sprintf("%u", -123) #=> "..4294967173"
```

When I do this on 1.8.7 I get this result:

```
"..18446744073709551493"
```

That's *similar* to the expected output, but is definitely not it.

When I do it on 1.9.2 however, I get the same number back as a string:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > sprintf("%u", -123)
 => "-123"
```

So there's actually two questions here.

1. Why would I be getting a different output to what the documentation says I would and
2. Why would Ruby 1.9.2 behave differently to 1.8.7, even when the documentation is quite specific about the output type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [1.8 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962) says that `%u` is for a 32-bit unsigned integer, and you're seeing it on a 64-bit unsigned integer, so that behavior is off. The [1.9 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Kernel.html#M000302) says that `%u` is the same as `%d`, so that behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and apt reply!